# Laravel 4.2 Mail won't send. Stuck in pretend

Tags: laravel-4

I'm trying to send mail. I followed the Laracast tutorial for sending mail with mandrill via https://laracasts.com/lessons/laravel-and-mandrill-in-minutes I also set up an event to trigger mail to send following this Laracast tutorial https://laracasts.com/series/build-a-laravel-app-from-scratch/episodes/27

Here is my `app/config/app.php` file

```
<?php

return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Debug Mode
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
| stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
| application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
|
*/

'debug' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
| the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
| your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
|
*/

'url' => 'http://localhost',

/*

);
```

My `app/config/mail.php` file

```
<?php

return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
|
*/

'driver' => 'mandrill',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => 'smtp.mailgun.org',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => 587,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => array('address' => 'admin@acme.com', 'name' => 'Acme'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => 'tls',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

'password' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail "Pretend"
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
| web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
| you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
|
*/

'pretend' => false,

);
```

my `app/config/services.php`

```
<?php

return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Third Party Services
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is for storing the credentials for third party services such
| as Stripe, Mailgun, Mandrill, and others. This file provides a sane
| default location for this type of information, allowing packages
| to have a conventional place to find your various credentials.
|
*/

'mailgun' => array(
    'domain' => '',
    'secret' => '',
),

'mandrill' => array(
    'secret' => 'MY SECRET API KEY IS HERE',
),

'stripe' => array(
    'model'  => 'User',
    'secret' => '',
),

);
```

Now when I hit the event that triggers the email to send, I check my `laravel.log` file and it says this

```
[2015-04-06 17:47:04] local.INFO: Pretending to mail message to: example@hotmail.com [] []
[2015-04-06 17:47:04] local.INFO: Acme.Registration.Events.UserRegistered was fired. [] []
```

It still says Pretending even though i have `'pretend' => false,` in my `app/config/mail.php` file. The email never sends. I'm using real emails (i'm just not displaying them in this post) Am I missing something here? What else can be triggering mail to be in pretend mode?

EDIT:

```
 <?php

 /*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Create The Application
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | The first thing we will do is create a new Laravel application instance
 | which serves as the "glue" for all the components of Laravel, and is
 | the IoC container for the system binding all of the various parts.
 |
 */

 $app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application;

 /*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Detect The Application Environment
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Laravel takes a dead simple approach to your application environments
 | so you can just specify a machine name for the host that matches a
 | given environment, then we will automatically detect it for you.
 |
 */

 $env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

     'local' => array('homestead'),

 ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a `local` or `dev` config environment setup that is overriding the mail settings.

Go to `app/config/local/mail.php` or `app/config/dev/mail.php` and change the `pretend` setting there (or delete the file if you dont want a separate config)

Comment: I did have a `local` directory within my `app` directory. All it has was a `app.php` file with just a debug setting. I deleted it, but I'm still getting the pretend message? Is there anywhere else that could be affecting it?

Comment: Did you set the environment in yout app.php ?

What is the output of this ? dd(App::environment());

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I'm getting `local` that must be it. But I do not see a setting where I can change this in my `app/config/app.php` . Maybe I removed it by mistake? Where can I edit this?

Comment: Sorry the environment setting is not in the app.php it resides in bootstrap/start.php

Comment: and did you set pretend to false in app/config/local/mail.php ?

Comment: + you should correct the settings in mail.php file.

host points to mailgun and password and username are null. Try filling the correct settings there

Comment: @JagdeepSingh ok i edited my question to show what i have in my `bootstrap/start.php` file

Comment: Since I'm using mandrill not mailgun. Should I just delete those options entirely?

Comment: i do not have a `app/config/local` directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74582/discussion-between-jagdeep-singh-and-xslibx).

Comment: I'm still experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If it is not problem with your settings, then:

1) Delete **vendor** folder

2) Run **composer install** to download all the dependencies

It helped me.